Lightning Protection for RF (L-Band or higher)
I want to protect an antenna port operating in the L-Band frequency range from lightning. I cannot use ready-made RF surge protector connectors. Instead, I was thinking of placing a GDT at the port input side, followed by a DC block, and then a TVS. However, since the TVS responds much faster than the GDT, the entire load would be taken by the TVS. The surge duration is 6.4µs (Ipeak), 69µs (Ipeak/2), with peak current and voltage values of 250V and 25A. Would this approach be suitable, or should it be solved in another way?


WRT to the DCB its hard to block DC while passing RF with minimal loss.  The broadcast people always liked a shorted quarter wave stub.  At FM radio frequencies the losses are essentially zero.  Look into how they solve the problem for inspiration.  A quarter wave stub at L band will be pretty small.  Your spec for lighting sounds unusual more like a power strip rating than a lighting strike.  You can buy COTS products cheaper than you can design and fabricate it although it is intellectually interesting to design so best of luck.

In general usage, we know that GDTs are slower than TVSs. It is necessary to use a TBU (HSP-High Speed Protector) as a buffer element to ensure the GDT operates first and to suppress the residual surge energy in the second protection stage using a TVS diode, thereby preventing damage to the back-end circuit. As shown in the figure below, I believe this method could be a solution for the RF port. Of course, the components may vary depending on the L-band frequency. This can be resolved using alternative components.


mali - Hi, Please can you clarify & improve this post: (a) Since you asked the question, and have now posted this answer, that should mean you have solved your own problem and the question can be considered closed. Is that what you mean? Or did you mean this as a response to the other answer? Or something else? (b) You have copied material from elsewhere & posted it on Stack Exchange. Therefore, to comply with the site referencing rule we need you to [edit] the post & add the original site name, the document / webpage title & its URL next to the copied material. TY
